# how to extract text from pdf in its base or original pdf font?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdfminer

I have a text based pdf for which i am trying to extract text using python. when I open pdf in pdf viewer or in browser its rendered correctly. however when I extract text from pdf it become gibberish, for example "1." becomes "'J..".

below is the snap of pdf rendered

[image: rendered font]

and extracted text

[image]

Also, while debugging pdf using pdfbox, it printed for some character corresponding unicode is missing

[image]

how can I extract text in its original font?

Comment: Please add some details. If possible, provide the PDF file or a part of it.

Comment: thanks for response, I hope edited info is sufficient.

Comment: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#how-come-i-am-not-getting-any-text-from-the-pdf-document%3F